# Finding points of intersection of curves

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: Find the area of the region(s) enclosed by the curves $y=cos 2x$ and $y= ln(x-1)$.

My first move was to plot the graphs of the 2 curves. Following is the graph of the 2 curves:

[image]

I sketched this graph roughly on paper, so I could only figure out the regions enclosed by the 2 curves and not the points of intersection.

To calculate the area, definite integration can be used but I need to know the upper and lower limits to integrate. For this, points of intersection of the 2 curves are required.

At the points of intersection, we know,

$cos 2x= ln(x-1)$

⇒ $e^{cos 2x} = x-1$

⇒$e^{cos 2x}-x+1 = 0$

How do I proceed after this? How to find the points of intersection? I could use a calculator or a tool on the Internet to find the points of the intersection but how to do it manually?

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Related:[$\ln(x)=\sin(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052237/why-are-numeric-methods-the-only-technique-available-to-solving-lnx-sinx/4694755)

Comment: You just have to solve the equation numerically for ex. using Newton,

Comment: IMHO, it could be better (to get some ideas) to plot $\cos(2x)-\log(x-1)$